# what version of OpenNTF Domino API can I use?

Tags: java, xpages, xpages-extlib

I would like to use the OpenNTF Domino API but to me it is not clear which version I can use?

The version of the extension library on the Domino server is 9.0.1.v00_00_20151122-0905 (upgrade pack 1).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Domino 9.0.1 Feature Pack 8, then 4.0.0 is the way to go. Otherwise, 3.2.1 is the right one.

The plan is for 3.2.x to get critical fixes (which is what 3.2.1 itself was over 3.2.0) but otherwise remain as-is, while future development will happen on the 4.x+ Java 8 path.

Comment: Hej! I read for version 3.x : This release requires Domino 9.0.1 and the REST API specifically requires the Extension Library 9.0.1_17 or higher. I suppose match that, thank you. (not using the rest api)

Answer (score 0):

The version of ODA will depend primarily on the Domino server version. It sounds like you're running Domino 8.5.3 and we've not specifically developed against that version. There was a lot of new functionality added in 9.0, specifically around NoteCollections, which is spread throughout the API. I did compile a version some years ago for 8.5.3, but it was never heavily tested or officially released. The server in question was upgraded to 9.0 before the project went live, so I'm not sure if I even have that version any more.

Version 4.0.0 is the first specifically compiled for 9.0.1 FP8 and will not work on previous versions. That's because it includes the new core Domino APIs (encryption, ID Vault etc) added with FP8. It's not currently compiled for Java 8, but work on that has already begun in the develop branch.

Version 3.2.1 is the recommended version for 9.0.1 up to FP7. It will still work on FP8, but only if there is no intention of using the new Domino APIs added with FP8. It will work with the base Extension Library as long as the Graph API REST functionality isn't required (not a regular requirement at this time), for which ExtLib 9.0.1_v00_17 is required. That's because additional hooks were added to the core Domino REST service functionality in ExtLib.

For any general discussion about ODA, there is an OpenNTF Domino API channel in the [OpenNTF Slack](https://openntf.slack.com/). The OpenNTF Slack team can be joined from the main OpenNTF website home page.